# Replace string that starts with specific character and ends with specific character in regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I wanted to replace a string section that starts with a specific character and ends with specific character. At below, I demonstrate test case.

```
var reg = /pattern/gi;

var str = "asdfkadsf[xxxxx]bb";

var test = str.replace(reg,"") == "asdfkadsfbb"

console.log(test);
```

Comment: In your example, you want to replace everything between the brackets?

Comment: Did you intend to replace `[xxxxx]` by `b` or was that a typo and the result should be `asdfkadsfbb` instead?

Comment: @AdamPlocher Yes but including brackets too.

Comment: @jerry I removed b character now.

Comment: +1 for providing the test-case code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This pattern should work for replace anything between brackets (including the brackets):

```
var reg = /(\[.*?\])/gi;

var str = "asdfkadsf[xxxxx]bb";

var test = str.replace(reg,"") == "asdfkadsfbb"
```

Comment: The case insensitivity doesn't really provide any usefulness in this context. Upvoted, regardless of the unnecessary `i`

Comment: @JeffShaver thanks, you're absolutely right.  I just took his code and modified it without even really paying much attention to that.

Comment: `()` are unnecessary, and `/\[[^\]]*\]/g` would be more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

based on your example, this works:

```
/\[.*]/gi
```

Comment: this looks the cleanest. but I think you are missing a backslash before the second bracket. `/\[.*\]/gi`